# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying this code I get an error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. The error is caused by line

`c1=(alp*bet-(alp*gam*(k-alp*bet*xi1))/(xi2-(alp*gam*xi1)))*((-lam2/lam1)*math.exp(lam1*x) + math.exp(lam2*x))`

but I can not find the problem. Any help appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

D=1  
k=0.001     
x0=0.5
L=1
s=0.01 
q=0.1  

lam1 =1/q + math.sqrt(1/q**2 + k/D)
lam2=1/q - math.sqrt(1/q**2 + k/D)

mu1=-1/q + math.sqrt(1/q**2 + k/D)
mu2=-1/q - math.sqrt(1/q**2 + k/D)

alp= 1/((-lam1)/(lam2))*math.exp(lam1*x0) + math.exp(lam2*x0)
bet=(s/(D*mu1))*math.exp(mu1*(x0-L))
gam= ((mu2)/(mu1))*math.exp((mu2-mu1)*L+mu1*x0)+math.exp(mu2*x0)
k=((s)/(D))*math.exp(mu1*(x0-L))
xi1=-lam2*math.exp(lam1*x0)+lam2*math.exp(lam2*x0)
xi2=mu2*math.exp((mu2-mu1)*L+mu1*x0)+mu2*math.exp(mu2*x0)
B=(k-(alp*bet*xi1))/(xi2-(alp*gam*xi1))


x = np.array([0, L, 10000])
c1=(alp*bet-(alp*gam*(k-alp*bet*xi1))/(xi2-(alp*gam*xi1)))*((-lam2/lam1)*math.exp(lam1*x) + math.exp(lam2*x))
c2=(k/mu1)-B*((mu2/mu1)*math.exp((mu2-mu1)*L+mu1*x)+math.exp(mu2*x))


c=np.piecewise(x, [x <= x0, x > x0], [c1, c2])
 

plt.plot(x,c)
```

Comment: `math.exp` parameter should be a scalar which like `3`. `lam1 * x` in your code result is `array([0.000000e+00, 2.000005e+01, 2.000005e+05])`

Comment: So, use `np.exp` instead, which takes an array and returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Genrally Python functions can't take an array input. If one pass array input to a function it gives The following error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
How to solve this?
To solve this, I use loop inside the function. Please see the following example:

```
import numpy as np
# pass array in function
T = 300 # Kelvin
kb = 1.38E-23 #kelvin-1 mole-1
rho = 1000 # Kg/m3
P = 1 #Pressure - atm
cmd = np.linspace(10,90,100)
def muA(T): #  dynamic viscosity Pa - s
    muA=0.00001708*((T/273.15)**1.5)*((393.396)/(T + 120.246))
    return muA
#
def slipC(P,cmd0): #slipcorrection
    slipC0 = []
    for mdx, cmd0 in enumerate(cmd0):
        print(mdx,cmd0)
        slipC = 1 + (2/(P*pow(10,2)*cmd0*(10**-3)*0.752))*(6.32 + 2.01*math.exp(-0.1095*P*pow(10,2)*0.752*cmd0*pow(10,-3)))
        slipC0 = slipC0 + [slipC]
    return slipC0
print(cmd)
print(slipC(P,cmd))
```